# Declare CGRect in if statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an if statement that checks if an array has a certain item:

```
    if ([[subTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@""]) {
```

and has this code inside it:

`CGRect CellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44);`

Then I have an else statement with the same thing but with different values, obviously.

It looks like this all together:

```
if ([[subTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    CGRect CellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44);
} else {
    CGRect CellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60);
}
```

Later in my code, I am trying to use CellFrame but it says it is undeclared. What is the proper way to make a CGRect if/else statement without having to put all of the code in each statement? Please say if I am unclear so I can provide more detail. Thanks.

Comment: I'm nitpicking here, but you shouldn't be naming variables starting with a capital letter ("CellFrame" should be "cellFrame")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the variable to be defined outside of the if/else statement. When you put it inside, it is only visible to code in that statement and will be destroyed on exit. Also, since only the height is different, you could assign the other parts of the rectangle outside of the if statement.

```
CGRect CellFrame;
CellFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0);
CellFrame.size.width = 300;
if([[subTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    CellFrame.size.height = 44;
} else {
    CellFrame.size.height = 60;
}
```